# how to add value from an array into a vector

Tags: java, blackberry

I am trying to store one value at a time from an array into a vector,so its like that the vector should increase its size dynamically.In my app,when we click start button,the value from the array goes to another page,where it is fetched,& then displayed,but wen i am trying to add that value into a vector & save it in persistent memory of blackberry,i can see only the last has been added into the vector,but i want the vector to one by one add all the values which i sent to the other page,here is the code,can anyone help me out

```
if ( quesNum != null && quesCount < quesNum.length )
{
   Vector data = new Vector();

   data.addElement ( TestScreen.quesNumber + "" );

   synchronized ( curQues )
   {

      curQuesnew = quesNum[quesCount];
      curQues.setContents ( curQuesnew + "" );
      curQues.commit();
   }

   synchronized ( disques )
   {

      System.out.println ( "value is " + data );
      disques.setContents ( data );
      disques.commit();
   }
   synchronized ( disques )
   {
      data = ( Vector ) disques.getContents(); 
   }

   if ( data.contains ( quesNum[quesCount] + "" ) )
   {
      xyz = quesNum[quesCount++];
      System.out.println ( "i shall overcome........." );

   }
   else
   {
      System.out.println ( "hardwork conqures all........." );
      xyz = quesNum[quesCount];
   }
   return xyz;
```

this is the value which i am sending to the other page everytime we click next button,so i am trying to store the values into a vector,everytime one value is being sent,bt the vector only stores the lastest value,nt the entire values//

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be my last attempt to answer your question.  Pay attention.

This is how you should manage your persistent vector.

```
static Vector data;

static PersistentObject disques = 
    PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(0x9e6d76868a999451L);
}

public static int test() {
    data = (Vector) disques.getContents();
    if (data == null) {
        System.out.println("Disques is empty!!");
        data = new Vector();
        disques.setContents(data);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Disques contains: " + data);
    }
    data.add("This is question " + data.size() + "\n");
    disques.commit();
}
```

Each time `test` is called, it fetches the persistent object's value and checks that it has been initialized.  If it has not been initialized, it initializes is to an empty Vector.  Then it adds one question to the vector an commits the changes.

If you don't understand this, I'm sorry but I'm not prepared to spend any more time trying to explain.  And I DEFINITELY am not prepared to spend any time trying to unpick the random mess that your application has turned into.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand the body of your question.  But here is some simple code to illustrate how to add values to a `Vector`.

```
Vector v = new Vector();
v.add("first string");
v.add("second string");
System.out.println(v.size());  // outputs "2"
System.out.println(v.get(0));  // outputs "first string"
System.out.println(v.get(1));  // outputs "second string"
```

Unless you have a specific reason for using `Vector`, it is better to use `ArrayList`.

Comment: Blackberry doesn't support ArrayList.

Comment: That sounds like a specific reason.  (Ugh!!)

Comment: I have to work with the Blackberry API almost every day at work and I often find myself saying 'Ugh!!!' ;)

Comment: Sir DaveJohnston,i hav posted my answer,can u plz help me with the code,i thnk u followed my problem.I hav to store each element frm the array into vector,not only the latest element which i am sending.plz help me with the code sir.

Comment: sir when i am trying to get the contents of the persistentobject first,& den store it in object i am facing problem.

Comment: @Arunabha - I think that the first paragraph of @DaveJohnston's answer points out what your problem is.  You code appears to be creating a new Vector and putting only one element into it.

Comment: @Stephen C - Sir actually that prob is solved,i hav declared the vector at the top,outside the method as static,& then add the elements,so now the vector is increasing in size slowly,but actually i am saving the vector into persistent memory,so that when we exit the app,& start again,the vector should contain those values which are being saved.But here i am facing prob nw,everytime i exit & start the app,the vector starts frm a new value,but i want the vector to hold the earlier value & add the new one.Plz help me sir

Comment: i mean i am saving 10 values at a time into the persistent memory of blackberry,but when i exit the app,& start again,those 10 values are not there,& the vector starts freshly with a new value at the first index,the want the vector to hold those 10 values,& strore the new value as 11th.i m declaring vector v=new vector at the top,is it for this reason that wen we restart the application,it starts freshly?

Comment: @Aranabha - That is explained in the second paragraph of @DaveJohnston's answer.  His answer says that you first call `getContents()` on the `PersistentObject` and cast the value to a Vector.  Then you add data to the `Vector`.  And finally, you call `commit()` to update the persistent object.

Comment: If you are trying to put more elements into an existing persisted Vector, you should not be doing `new Vector()`.  Read @DaveJohnston's answer.  Or look at the Restaurant code sample in the "BlackBerry Java Development Environment Development Guide"

Comment: @Stephen C-Actually,when i am doing getContents(),prior to setContents(),then my app is not running,& 2ndly if i dont create new vector(),the values are not being added to the vector for the first time.i am giving my code,plz see.

Comment: @Stephen C-Is there any process by which we can add value to a vector without declaring it as new vector().

Comment: @Stephen C- And whenever i try to call get.Contents() earlier to setContents(),i am getting null pointer exception

Comment: @Stephen C-whenever i try to declare a vector like dis public static  Vector data;instead of the new Vector(),& addelement to it,& do the getContents() & setContents();its throwing null pointer expception,cant we add element to a vector without declaring it as new Vector().

Comment: @Arunabha - see my other answer.  That shows you how to do it.  If you still don't understand, I'd advise you to take some lessons in basic Java programming.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, but I can see that you are creating a new Vector every time.

```
Vector data = new Vector();
data.addElement ( TestScreen.quesNumber + "" );
```

So of course `data` is only going to have a single element in it.  I am guessing `disques` is a `PersistentObject`?  So the first thing to do would be to get the existing contents (like you do later on):

```
synchronized ( disques ) {
    data = ( Vector ) disques.getContents(); 
}
```

Then add your new content to `data` and `commit` it back to the `PersistentObject`.